# Inconsistent permissions for dnf install

Tags: linux, fedora, sudo, package-management, dnf

Why do I *not* need to install as `root` when the shell "guesses" the package I need to execute a command?

For example:

```
(cseymour) : ~ $ dnf install rogue
Error: This command has to be run under the root user.
(cseymour) : ~ $ rogue
bash: rogue: command not found...
Install package 'rogue' to provide command 'rogue'? [N/y] y


 * Waiting in queue... 
The following packages have to be installed:
 rogue-5.4.5-19.fc24.x86_64 The original graphical adventure game
Proceed with changes? [N/y] y


 * Waiting in queue... 
 * Waiting for authentication... 
 * Waiting in queue... 
 * Downloading packages... 
 * Requesting data... 
 * Testing changes... 
 * Installing packages...
```

and so on, successfully installing the package without requiring root password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is small package [PackageKit-command-not-found](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/PackageKitCommandNotFound) installed in Fedora, that makes this happen. The policy is configured in `/etc/PackageKit/CommandNotFound.conf`.

The authentication is done using [PolicyKit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) (over D-bus), where you already granted installation of new package using PackageKit GUI. The respective file is `usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/org.freedesktop.packagekit.rules` allowing to install packages for locally logged in users in `wheel` group:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-install" &&
        subject.active == true && subject.local == true &&
        subject.isInGroup("wheel")) {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

If you are not satisfied with this behaviour, you can always uninstall this package (`dnf remove PackageKit-command-not-found`) and the packages will not get installed automatically.

Comment: Thanks so much! Given this is installed by default, why is it that dnf deems to use a password request rather than something similar? Are these differing behaviours intentional?

Comment: Because `dnf` is not `PackageKit` and the rule above is only for PackageKit. DNF is standard command-line tool, that needs `root` privileges, but PackageKit is using authentication using D-Bus and *some* backend already running as a root.

Comment: @csey I agree that it's inconsistent. You can also install software without a password using the GNOME Software GUI tool. I think it's mostly just that the behavior which we decided is okay for command-not-found and GUI installs is to install packages from already-configured repos. Since Fedora in general avoids activating services simply on installation, the risk of this is fairly low. On the other hand, DNF can do a lot of other things, many of them dangerous.

Comment: @mattdm thank you for the addition and background, which I was missing (still only few years around Fedora). I will add it to the answer or you can edit it in, since it can be interesting also for others.